# Fastest way to find an unique elements out of given numbers

Tags: algorithm, optimization, xor

I have n numbers. n <= 1000000. Each number will be positive integer and less than 10^9.

It is sure that there will be only one number will occur once, rest will occur twice or even number of times.

The shortest solution I know is the result of XOR of all numbers. I want to know

- What will be the complexity of the standard XOR solution.
- How can we optimize the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  I understand the input, but you're talking about XOR - how does that help you find a unique element?

Comment: @op_amp, but if you `XOR` any element odd number of times...

Comment: sounds like homework  :)

Comment: @Blank Xavier, @Andrey: Because all elements except for the unique element he's searching for will appear an even number of times, they will all cancel each other out, leaving only the bit values of the single element that didn't have a match in the collection.

Comment: It's funny how I hated homework in college, but now it's more fun than actual work.

Comment: @Dan Its not a homework. I solved [link] (https://www.spoj.pl/ranks/OLOLO/) . My solution took more than 1 sec while people have done it 0.10 seconds.

Comment: @op_amp: Is it possible that the problem isn't with the algorithm, but rather with your implementation of it?

Comment: @op_amp, You solved, or "we" solved  ;)  enjoy the challenge, wish I had time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XOR algorithm is the right algorithm and the fastest one. The slow part is the way that you are reading the input.

For instance, `scanf` in C is slower than handrolling your own number algorithm with `getchar` (or even better `getchar_unlocked`). On the SPOJ problem that you mentioned, I got an improvement from 1.35s to 0.14s just by making this change. I'm sure that the remaining 0.04 to get the best time on the site is just due to better low-level IO than my code.

Comment: Not exactly the answer of my query but solved the purpose of asking the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

XORing all the numbers will be of O(n) complexity, since you'll need to visit each element only once.

I can't think of any way to optimize this further, given your requirements. XOR is a very cheap operation, and the nature of the problem requires you to visit each element at least once: otherwise, you cannot possibly know which value is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for hashing. A raw solution would be to use the unique number as a key to your hash table. If that is possible, then you can probably use the hashing algorithm. A simple example is to use the numbers as an index in an array. Now, the space will be too much (I mean too too much), but can be optimized further.

Comment: The premise of the problem is the only one number will occur once and the others will occur *an even number of times*

Comment: The problem statement says that all but one number will exist in the list an even number of times. So your sample input would not occur.